# In Blazor, Query a Database and Update UI on a Set Interval

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a separate program that updates request status in a DB. My UI needs to reflect those updates when they happen.

```
@page "/RequestDetail/{RequestId:int}"
@inject IDbContext _db;

<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <h3>Request @RequestId Detail</h3>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <ol type="1">
            @foreach (var detail in _requestDetails)
            {
                <li>@detail.Step @detail.Status - @detail.Success @detail.Error</li>
            }
        </ol>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public int RequestId { get; set; }

    private Timer? _timer;
    private IEnumerable<RequestDetail> _requestDetails = new List<RequestDetail>();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        _requestDetails = _db.GetRequestDetail(RequestId);
    }

    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            var timerCallBack = new TimerCallback(_ =>
            {
                _requestDetails = _db.GetRequestDetail(RequestId);
                Console.WriteLine("Timer Callback reached.");
            });
            int delay = 5000;
            int interval = 5000;
            _timer = new Timer(timerCallBack, null, delay, interval);
        }
    }
}
```

The Console.Writeline appears reliably, but the UI does not update. I've tried:

```
if (firstRender)
        {
            var timerCallBack = new TimerCallback(_ =>
            {
                _requestDetails = _db.Views.GetRequestDetail(RequestId);
                StateHasChanged();
                Console.WriteLine("Timer Callback reached.");
            });
            int delay = 5000;
            int interval = 5000;
            _timer = new Timer(timerCallBack, null, delay, interval);
        }
```

But receive the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The current thread is not associated with the Dispatcher. 
Use InvokeAsync() to switch execution to the Dispatcher when triggering rendering or component state.'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: There is no RequestID.  You are using OnInitialized() which gets called when a class is constructed.  Where are you constructing the _db class object?  You have html definition of the text but nothing the parses or creates the class.

Comment: The RequestID is being fed into the component via parameter. I've added it to the code.

I am constructing the _db class object in program.cs and injecting it into the component through dependency injection.

Comment: OnInitialized() is called in Blazor when the Blazor Component is initialized, either as it's own page, or as an html element in another page.

Comment: Does RequestID have a value?  Where in your code Blazor Component is initialized?  Put a break point OnInitialize and see if you get there and if RequestID has a value.

Comment: Have you tried using `InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modifying your OnAfterRender this way, to make sure that Timer callback is executed in UI thread.

```
protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        var timerCallBack = new TimerCallback(async _ =>
        {
            _requestDetails = _db.GetRequestDetail(RequestId);
            Console.WriteLine("Timer Callback reached.");
            await InvokeAsync(() => StateHasChanged());
        });
        int delay = 5000;
        int interval = 5000;
        _timer = new Timer(timerCallBack, null, delay, interval);
    }
}
```

By using `InvokeAsync` you ensure that it's executed on the UI thread.